# Сформировать ссылку после заполнения формы. Как в Яндекс Деньги. Помогите!

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, друзья!
Как реализовать следующее:
Допустим есть три imput для последующего GET запроса:
1. Название (переменная x)
2. Стоимость (переменная z)
3. Комментарий (переменная y)
Пользователь заполняет форму, нажимает на кнопку "Создать" и например в textarea получает ссылку:
**site.ru/?x=тестовое%20название&z=50.00&y=привет%20мир**

Благодарен за любую помощь или направление!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну конкатенацию строк никто не отменял, разве что обработку пробелов и других символов нужно добавить. Т.е. пробел - %20 и другие символы.
Вот тут [Почитать про encode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp).
Ну а реализация проста :

```
var name = $("input1").val();
var cost = $("input2").val();
var comment = $("input3").val();
var tmp = "site.ru/?x"+name+"&z="+cost+"&y="+comment;
var result = encodeURI(tmp);
$("textarea#tar1").html(result);
console.log(result);
```

**UPDATE**

https://jsfiddle.net/j14xpfwo/4/ вот решение (хоть и не очень красивое).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я только начинаю изучать java. Вы могли бы помочь мне на примере https://jsfiddle.net/j14xpfwo/ ? Я попытался воспроизвести эту функцию, но у меня ничего не выходит(

Comment: @SergeyPlaxin Рад помочь! Ну раз вам надо на java , то добавьте плз метку java в ваш вопрос. JFY - javascript !=java ;)  . По сабжу - [почитать тут ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters) про класс URLEncoder  который предоставляет нужный функционал. Фактически - тоже самое что и в моем коде ). Ну и собственно в java нет $("input") т.к. это синтаксис Jquery библиотеки на JS. В java есть формы, получить объекты на форме не является трудоемкой задачей.

Comment: Вот вам исправленный ваш вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/j14xpfwo/4/. Видимо вам все таки нужен javascript вариант =)